# Selectable Table Rows and Passing Selection Info to new Component

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, components

I have an Angular 4 component with a table as the code below shows. I would like to have every row clickable to open a angular2-modal https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal with detail information to the selected row (clinic). I'm new to angular and I do not know how to pass the information which row (clinic) is clicked to the presumably new component and how to make those rows clickable in the first place.
A bonus would be a pretty hover effect in the table.

```
<tbody *ngIf="!isEditing">
    <tr *ngFor="let clinic of clinics">
      <td><b>{{clinic.clinicCode}}</b><br>
      <font size="-2">Last Update: <br>
      {{clinic.lastUpdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a' : 'UTC' }}</font></td>
      <td>{{clinic.clinicName}}</td>
      <td>{{clinic.street}}</td>
      <td>{{clinic.zip}}</td>
      <td>{{clinic.town}}</td>
      <td>{{clinic.countryCode}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" (click)="enableEditing(clinic)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="deleteClinic(clinic)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with the bonus, the easyest:

**CSS:**

```
td:hover{
   background-color:red;
   color:white
}
```

**HTML**

1.Change the button markup as this:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" (click)="enableEditing(clinic)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button>
```

So you can get 'clicnic' object inside enableEditing().

2.You can also get the id for each one by

```
<tr *ngFor="let clinic of clinics; let i=index">
```

where i is the index indeed. And you can do

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" (click)="doSomething(i)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button>
```

**Typescript**

```
doSomething(id){
   console.log(clinics[id]);
}
```

And in the new component you will need `@Input` to get the 'clinic' object/information.

Comment: Thank you it really helped me to understands the basic concepts.